# Pentium 3 freezes on XP. (SSE2)

Tags: windows-xp, freeze, intel-pentium, exceptions

On my old work PC I often encounter freezes until it is rebooted. I can work all day but something happens and my computer stops responding (mouse freezes too). I'm aware of Pentium 3 issues with SSE2 code, but when it does I get a 0xc000001d exception or message box that application can,t work with this type of processors, without freezing. I am getting this exception in x64dbg with a Qt lib based application.  More often the freezing happens with older versions of browsers when I open more than 2 tabs (Firefox, Nightly, Opera, which is SSE compliant) and with Visual Studio 2010. But I can't reproduce this error. I don't have any problem with old software (released before 2005).

My PC: Windows XP pro SP3, Pentium III 701 MHz, 896 MB memory (all of DIMM SDRAM what we have). Please don't ask me to change PC, cause our hardware on ISA bus works only with this configuration about 30 years. How we can to prevent this error? Thank you!

Comment: Run Hardware Diagnostics and Update all Drivers

Comment: @ John, where does one update XP drivers from?

Comment: You need to get the web support site for the PC Manufacturer and look for XP drivers. That is always how to update drivers.  If no drivers for XP then the OP is out of luck

Comment: If you are hardware dependant to keep something work-related running, you'd do well to research how to duplicate that machine to one as new as you can possibly go & still have compatibility. Acronis do a Universal Restore as part of their backup suite, which can in effect duplicate that machine to another of dissimilar hardware… but finding an old enough version might be an issue. Speak to Acronis; tell them you have this specific requirement. [I've seen similar situations where you have millions of bucks' worth of machinery that will only run on one specific computer type, long out of date]

Comment: `Please don't ask me to change PC, cause our hardware on ISA bus works only with this configuration about 30 years` - I don't think you have any choice. The chances are it is slowly dying and one day, it will not work at all, not matter what you try.